# MassTransit consumers didn't acknowledge some messages

Tags: masstransit

I have a question about some strange behaviour of consumer.

Recently we had strange situation on production environment. Two consumers on two different microservices were stuck at some messages. The first one was holding 20 messages from rabbitMQ queue and the second one 2 messages and they weren't processing them. These messages were visible as Unacked in RabbitMQ for two days. They went back to Ready state just when that two microservices were restarted. At that time when consumers took this messages the whole program was processing thousands messages per hour, so basically our Saga and all consumers were working. When these messages went back to Ready state they were processed in one second after that so I don't think that it's problem with them.

The messages are published by Saga to Exchange and besides these two stucked consumers we have also EventLogger consumer subscribed to all messages and this EventLogger processed this 22 messages normally without any problems (from his own queue). Also we have connected Application Insights to consumers and there is no information about receiving these 22 messages by these two consumers (there are information about receiving it by EventLogger).

The other day we had the same issue with one message on test environment.

Recently we updated version of MassTransit in our project from version 6.2.0 to 7.1.6 and before that we didn't notice any similar issues with consumers but maybe it's just coincidence. We also have retry, redelivery, circuit breaker and in memory outbox mechanisms but I don't think that's problem with them because the consumer didn't even start to process these 22 messages.

Do you have any suggestions what could happened to this consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when a consumer doesn't even start to consume the message once it has been delivered to MassTransit by RabbitMQ, it could be an issue resolving the consumer from the container, such as a dependency to another backing service (database, log server, file, network connection, device, etc.).

The message remains unacknowledged on the broker because the transport/delivery mechanism to the consumer is waiting for a resource to become available. If there isn't anything in the logs for that time period indicating an issue with a resource, it's hard to know what could have blocked those messages from being consumed. The fact that they were ultimately consumed once the services were restarted seems to indicate the message content itself was fine.

Monitoring the *lack* of message consumption (and likely an associated queue depth increase) would give an indication that the situation has occurred. If it happens again, I'd increase the logging detail levels to see if the issue occurs again and can then be identified.